# Publisher - Consument (publisher as controller) rabbitmq and redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis, rabbitmq, consumer, publisher

I have functional code, but I want to ask if this approach is correct when I use 'publisher in the controller' or if it is commonly used that way. I will post the entire code here where I use RabbitMQ and Redis. If you have any comments on other aspects of the code, feel free to write them.

Do i need to have redis config when its not being used?
Are the values stored into redis only by the key: iot-data?

**DOCKER**

```
services:
  redis:
    container_name: "redis-server"
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/redis_data:/var/lib/redis/data

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
```

**REDIS**

```
app.properties
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.redis.host=127.0.0.1
spring.redis.port=6379
```

```
public class RedisConfig {
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
}
```

- Redis controller just for testing the redis cache

```
@RestController
public class RedisController {
    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/api/redis")
    public List<String> readIotData() {
        return redisTemplate.opsForList().range("iot-data", 0, 20);
    }
```

**RABBITMQ**

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitmqConfig {
    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange fanout() {
        return new FanoutExchange("iot-data");
    }

    private static class ReceiverConfig {
        @Bean
        public Queue myQueue() {
            return new Queue("", true);
        }

        @Bean
        public Binding binding(FanoutExchange fanout, Queue myQueue) {
            return BindingBuilder.bind(myQueue).to(fanout);
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class RabbitmqListener {
    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "iot-data";

    @RabbitListener(autoStartup="true",
            bindings=@QueueBinding(value = @Queue,
                    exchange=@Exchange(name=EXCHANGE_NAME,
                            type= ExchangeTypes.FANOUT,
                            durable = "true")))
    public void consoleOutputReceiver(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
    }

    @RabbitListener(autoStartup="true",
            bindings=@QueueBinding(value = @Queue,
                    exchange=@Exchange(name=EXCHANGE_NAME,
                            type= ExchangeTypes.FANOUT,
                            durable = "true")))
    public void redisOutputReceiver(String message) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        CreateDto dto = mapper.readValue(message, CreateDto.class);

        redisTemplate.opsForList().leftPush("iot-data", message);
    }
}
```

- rabbitmq publisher

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class Controller {

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public void post(@RequestBody CreateDto dto) throws Exception{
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");

        try(Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel()) {

            channel.exchangeDeclare("iot-data", "fanout", true);

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String jsonDto = mapper.writeValueAsString(dto);

            channel.basicPublish("iot-data","", null, jsonDto.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```